# What the ? In debug mode In Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I am using debugging in IntelliJ, for some of the values I am getting `?` as the output value what does it means I am not able to figure this out.

[image: Debug Image]

Comment: You probably need to add your code so that people can help you understand this.

Comment: Drill down a bit more into `values`.

Comment: Have you customised the Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | **Java** or **Java Type Renderers** settings? If so - attach the screenshots. Any custom plugins you use?